# shutdown() and close() not found in 'None'

Tags: python, sockets, port-scanning

I'm using python 3.8, and trying to learn to code for networking; I've seen some examples from 2014 with code for a port scanner, which is defines the port scanning function like this:

```
def pscan(port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        con = sock.connect((target, port))
        with print_lock:
            print("Port:",port,"is open.")
        con.shutdown()
        con.close()
```

When I implement this in pycharm I see the message:
"Cannot find reference 'shutdown' in 'None'
and
"Cannot find reference 'close' in 'None'

The code runs, but never seems to stop... I am guessing that it is due to not properly closing the socket.

Can anyone educate me as to where my error is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to **[edit]** your questions, for example to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`connect` doesn't return anything.

I think you want this:

```
def pscan(port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect((target, port))
        with print_lock:
            print("Port:",port,"is open.")
        sock.shutdown()
        sock.close()
```

Also, no need to call `shutdown` if you're going to immediately call `close` afterwards.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, and I had tried that prior to posting this question, and it did remove the 'error', however it did not seem to solve the issue of the script running endlessly. I understand that something like this can run for quite some time, but I have implemented this with threading, and have had previous iterations end successfully; this seems to go on forever though. Am I missing something else?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "script running endlessly"  You've only shown a few lines of socket code.